# Swiper js autoplay slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I'm having autoplay Swiper js slider, which by default displays one slide at a time, I need to display three slides (or images) at a time, would you please advise me how to adjust it.

```
 <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
   <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
 </div>
 <!-- Add Pagination -->
 <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
 <!-- Add Arrows -->
 <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
 <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>

 <!-- Swiper JS -->

 <script src="../package/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
      <script>
       var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        spaceBetween: 30,
        centeredSlides: true,
        autoplay: {
        delay: 2500,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
      pagination: {
       el: '.swiper-pagination',
       clickable: true,
       },
      navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
     });
   </script>
```

Comment: slidesPerView parameter: https://swiperjs.com/api/#parameters. Docs demo: https://swiperjs.com/demos/#multiple_slides_per_view. Responsive brekapoints demo: https://swiperjs.com/demos/#responsive_breakpoints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 2500,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/css/swiper.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any differences between my code and yours my friend

Comment: because i want to display three slides at a time, this code shows one slide at a time only

Comment: @Adel Updated check now

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is wondering, as of now it's available a parameter called "slidesPerGroup", and it takes the number of how many slides you want to slide.